# vnc disconnects after password is entered

Tags: windows-vista, mac, vnc

I'm attempting to connect to a Vista machine running RealVNC from a Mac.  I've tried using both the applet and Chicken of the VNC to connect.  The following is the traffic between the two PCs:

```
balance -pf 5900 41.193.x.x
-< 12
RFB 003.008\0A

-> 12
RFB 003.008\0A

-< 2
\01\02
-> 1
\02
-< 16
\9CaZH^B,\B5M\11\1A\CD\87Ibm
-> 16
\C8\DE\CF\92\FA\CF\CBe\D0\B0\A1A\9D\8F\0C6
-< 4
\00\00\00\00
-> 1
\00
-< 0
```

The applet log displays the following:

```
CConn: connected to host 41.193.x.x port 5900
CConnection: Server supports RFB protocol version 3.8
CConnection: Using RFB protocol version 3.8
main: rdr.EndOfStream: EndOfStream
```

What are the things I can check.  I'm reasonably certain I'm passing the correct *password* and obviously the ports are open.

Comment: Every time I've had the same problem it turned out to be an incorrect password, no matter how sure I originally was that I was using the correct one.

Comment: How are the two computers connected? Judging by the IP address above, this box is connected directly to the internet (or probably shouldn't have that IP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the Vista machine is running normally? For example, I've had this problem (enter password and RealVNC immediately disconnects) when the machine has crashed and is "waiting for programs to close"

Comment: I'm sad to say it was the password.  Asking the remote end to recheck what they set the password to fixed the problem.  Thanks for the responses - sorry it wasn't more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that several VNC servers use this as "End of Session"  Are you sure that the Vista machine does not have firewall rules or that the VNC server has the correct permissions for the user you're attempting to log in as?

Mac OS X Server does this, too, when you use a VNC client from another platform (Linux or Windows).  You get the same "EndOfStream" message as output from vncviewer (Linux) or in the logs of TightVNC or RealVNC (Windows.)

Comment: I am on Linux had to use FullColor and AutoSelect args to get pass of that dreaded EndOfStream error:
`xvnc4viewer -FullColor -AutoSelect jenkins-mac-mini2`

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling adaptive quality and forcing the highest colour depth possible in your vncviewer application before attempting to connect to the remote server.  I've found that fixes a few issues when one side or the other doesn't get the adaptive stuff right and/or has a different internal implementation.